# Logarithmic and Exponential Graph Intersections

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

So given equations $log$ base $a$ of $x$ and $a$ to the $x$th power, I am asked to determine the values of $a$ for which the two graphs have one point of intersection and then the values of $a$ for which the two graphs have two points of intersection.

For the first problem, I know $0<a<1$ is an answer, but I feel like that there should also be an answer in the interval $a>1$, except that I don't quite know how to get that answer. And that also leaves me unable to answer question 2 as the answer would be in the form $1<a<$(some value where the two graphs intersect).

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: mess with the slider [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7pihxap5rw) to get an initial intuition

Comment: Oh I've already done that before, but I still don't quite get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to notice that since the two functions are inverses of each other, all the intersections lie on $y=x$. So you know the solutions satisfy the inverse of $x=a^x \implies a=x^{1/x}$, which has a max at $e^{1/e}$. Therefore, we have one intersection when $a\in(0,1)$, two when $a\in(1, e^{1/e})$, and zero when $a\in (\infty,0] \cup (e^{1/e}, \infty)$

Comment: I'm sorry if this ought to be obvious, but how does $e$ yield a maximum?

Comment: @Helena because $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{1/x} \right] = -x^{1/x-2} (\ln x -1)$, which is zero when $x=e$. (there's more work to show this is the only critical point and is a max, not a min, but this should suffice)